# How to change the final downloaded video format with Video Downloader

Tags: video, file-format

I use **Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS**.

I downloaded and installed the app: **Video Downloader**, which is saved on:

> /snap/bin/video-downloader

I wonder if there is a way to change the final downloaded video format.

The default format is ***.webm**.

I cannot to see any menu to set this.

Any idea? ???

BTW: I've been trying to perform the suggested idea from @andrew.46, but I just get the following error message:

```
No se pudieron cargar los esquemas de /snap/video-downloader/current/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas: Falló al abrir el archivo «/snap/video-downloader/current/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled»: open() falló: No existe el archivo o el directorio.
```

(Cannot to load the schemes from /snap... The file or folder doesn't exist)

So... I don't know what to do about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Video-Downloader is an application that uses youtube-dl as its engine and to make things simple the application has masked most of the many, many options of youtube-dl. Fair enough I guess.

By default 'free' codecs and containers are preferred but if you would like to use *non-free* codecs and containers you can use the following command:

```
gsettings --schemadir /snap/video-downloader/current/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas set com.github.unrud.VideoDownloader prefer-mpeg true
```

And to return to the defaults values you can issue the above command again substituting 'false' for 'true'.

So as an example I have used the short YouTube clip where Linus Torvalds demonstrates the correct pronunciation of 'Linux' [found here...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9JGP-HeO8w). Results are as follows:

- VideoDownloader set to `prefer-mpeg false` and 1080P: Container is webm with VP9 Video and Opus Audio
- VideoDownloader set to `prefer-mpeg true` and 1080P: Container is mp4 with H.264 Video and AAC Audio.

Which I suspect is pretty much what you are after; for *more extensive* options you would be better to use youtube-dl directly from the command line...

Comment: Thank you so much @andrew.46 !!! BTW: Where can I get more help about the "youtube-dl" command? ???

Comment: @Juan Once you have downloaded youtube-dl the command `youtube-dl --help` will show a plethora of options. Have a great day!!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is based on youtube-dl you could change the snap and the request how it works. (as suggested by @andrew.46 )

But since I believe this is a bit too complicated, I suggest, that you install ffmpeg(if it isn't already installed) and then convert it to the format you want after you downloaded it.

[The simplest way is: `ffmpeg -i input.webm output.mp4`](https://ffmpeg.org/)

(Replace mp4 with the Container you wish).